# Can't find origin in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, xmpp, openfire

I have an xmpp server (Openfire) in my local PC. I made a javascript chat client on my hosted website that is connecting to my openfire server. So this is a live chat support.
It works perfectly in every browser except all versions of Internet Explorer.
I got the following error:
Can't find "http://www.heavenlypictures.hu" origin in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
In openfire I enabled access from all domains, and I have the following cross domain policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="5222,5223,7070,7443" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I'm using JQUERY post and AJAX requests for connect to the xmpp server.

What is the problem? Why IE can't access?

You can try it here:
http://www.heavenlypictures.hu/contact/chat/chat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work on IE10, where [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is finally supported?  If so, your problem is that you need to use [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767443.aspx) on IE8 and IE9.

Also, check to make sure your BOSH, JavaScript, and HTML URLs are all HTTPS or all HTTP, not a mix.  IE10 enforces this for same-origin where many other browsers don't.

Comment: Sorry, it works on IE10. So the problem is that older versions do not support CORS. I checked the link you sent about XDomainRequest, but I couldn't get it to work on IE9 and IE8, but I will figure it out. Thanks.